# Cannot use custom font in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, fonts, truetype

I have 3 .ttf files in my iPhone app. They represent these 3 fonts:

- Gotham Rounded Book
- Gotham Rounded Medium
- Gotham Rounded Bold

I put all of them in my .plist, but only 2 show up when I do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Gotham Rounded"]);
```

This is what gets logged:

```
"GothamRoundedMedium-Regular",
"GothamRoundedBook-Regular"
```

What is going wrong here? Screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to the reason that you haven't included `gothamroundedbold.ttf` in your target as in image.
Select assistance navigator
Check the membership of the font file that is missing. In my case it is checked and in your case it should be unchecked.
[image]
`