# Loading Custom UIFonts in xCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So I'm having a couple of problems actually.  The first is that I want to use a "Font Suitcase" file as a custom font in an iOS app and haven't been able to get it to work.  Not only that, but I haven't been able to properly use a .ttf file either.  Here are the steps that I've taken to try and make it work:

1. Imported the file into my supporting files in xCode.
2. Added the file name, e.g. "badaboom.TTF" into the Info.plist file
3. Called UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Badaboom" size:20.0];

I also used the code found [here](http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/list-of-fonts-available-on-the-iphone/) to see if the font was even being loaded and it doesn't appear either.  This applies for both ttf and font suitcase files.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: Have you made sure that the font is a valid font and not corrupted? Have you also checked that the file name that you are putting into the info.plist file is **exactly** the same as the filename of the font itself?

Comment: So, the file name is exactly the file name of the font (do I need the entire path?), but every font I try has the "Invalid 'kern' subtable" error if it's a ttf, although it does show up in the font book.

Comment: I guess that's why. Have you searched Google to see if the same problem has arisen for anyone else. Also, did you receive an error when adding it to fontbook?

Comment: It seems to happen for other people when they add things to font book (the error appears when you try to install it) but not really matter because the font is still usable and appears as a normal font in the font book, with the font suitcase files they all work without errors in font book

Comment: Checkout this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10743093/468724

Comment: Still got nothing, although the box was unchecked, it didn't help.  Also, the boxes were checked for both of the font suitcase files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add your fonts as resources.

So do  the following steps:

- Go to your **project settings**
- Select your **target**
- Go to **Build Phases**
- Add the custom font to **Copy Bundle Resources**

With this and the code you posted you should now be able to load custom fonts

Comment: This was actually the problem, I'll note earlier the alternate way to get to it is by checking that "add target" box in the properties of the item, but the actual problem was that the file name was mistyped in the Info.plist file.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure you added it in the info.plist under the key "Fonts provided by application" and sure you are using the proper name of the font?

Answer (score 2):

Double click on the TTF file in Finder.  Look at the title bar.  The name inside preview has to be exactly the same as what is in your quote [UIFont fontWithName:@"" size:20.0];

It's case sensitive.